# Firefox download window open in the second monitor

Tags: windows-7, firefox, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors, one is the main and the second is a TV.
I was trying to download a file from SkyDrive for about 40 minutes without success, the popup window never comes up.

Then the movie on TV ends and I choose PC HMDI input to see the second Window screen and there is, the about 80 download windows waiting for my approbation to start the download.
I'm very annoyed.

So, There's any way to configure Firefox to open all the Windows(pop up/msgbox) over the main window?

I'm talking about this window.
[image]